# Work done in an isolated system

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, work, gas, reversibility

Question: An ideal gas is allowed to expand both reversibly and irreversibly in an isolated system. If $T$ is the initial temperature and $T^\prime$ is the final temperature then compare the final temperature in each process?

In this question how can the work be done if the system is isolated? Wouldn’t it mean that no external agent is present?

Comment: Yes.  This question is poorly posed

Comment: Do you mean a closed system instead of an isolated system?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Question: An ideal gas is allowed to expand both reversibly and irreversibly in an isolated system. If $T$ is the initial temperature and $T^\prime$ is the final temperature then compare the final temperature in each process?

> In this question how can the work be done if the system is isolated? Wouldn’t it mean that no external agent is present?

Presumably, they do not mean the *gas* alone is an isolated system, but rather that the gas is a closed system. The gas might be thought of as interacting with another subsystem, the combination of which is isolated.

The term "isolated" here might be more colloquial and might just mean very well thermally insulated. (E.g., no heat transfer.)

In the reversible case, the gas presumably does work on a piston (or whatever) and the total system could be considered isolated (but the gas is a closed system since it can exchange energy with another system via the piston).

Regardless, you probably know the temperature change for the adiabatic free expansion. (It is trivial and easily Googleable and I bet this is what they are looking for.)

And, the case of adiabatic expansion of an ideal gas against a piston is also well-known and easily Bingable.

Comment: Yes.  As traditionally defined in thermodynamics, a closed system is one with no mass transfer between the system and the surrounding, and an isolated system is a closed system with no energy (heat or work) transfer between the system and the surroundings.